# Assign action url dynamically to POST method

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I've simple asp form in which I get few text fields, these values are stored in hidden fields. On button click I call post method as

```
<form method="post" action="https://test.mydomain.com/payment/AcceptRequestServlet"
```

this is working as desired. Now I got another requirement that based on a choice (captured through radio button) I should post to another url

```
e.g If option 1 then 
     <form method="post" action="https://test.mydomain.com/payment/AcceptRequestServlet1"
    If option 2 then
     <form method="post" action="https://test.mydomain.com/payment/AcceptRequestServlet2"
```

Is it possible to implement this.

Comment: From the question so far, this is either pure client-side, or Java platform. Why is it tagged ASP.NET and VS2012?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch form action using javascript.

```
 if(case1)
  {
   document.myform.action ="https://test.mydomain.com/payment/AcceptRequestServlet1";
  }
  else

  {
    document.myform.action ="https://test.mydomain.com/payment/AcceptRequestServlet2";
  }
```

Assuming form is `myform`.